# Wildcard date form in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wildcard

I want to check if string satisfies condition (*First, second, fourth, fifth, seventh, eighth, ninth and tenth* character can be any number. *Third and sixth* must be forward slash.) Like date format. I need this:

```
if (date !== SOMETHING ){
    alert("Wrong input!");}
```

Comment: Erm, you know what the format of the expected input is, parse it into a `Date` object, then compare?

Comment: Regex is also an option but I'm not totally clear on what the requirement is yet.

Comment: @Vld  Requirement is that date must be in dd/mm/yyyy form. Otherwise `alert("Invalid input!")` .

Comment: In that case parse using regex for perceived validity, and then parse into a `Date` to check if the date is valid (February 30th and so on). There are probably a bunch of libraries that can do it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to match the date with a regular expression (this one ensures that it matches the format (DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY):

```
if (date.match( /^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/ )) {
   alert("Valid input!");
} else {
  alert("Wrong input!");
}
```

This regular expression `/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/` returns `true` if the string matches the following pattern:

- 2 digits
- Forward slash
- 2 digits
- Forward slash
- 4 digits

Here's a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ah2tq96/3/) that shows it working.

Here's another (more "Eloquent") solution (return a JavaScript Date through a function):

```
function findDate(string) {
  var dateTime = /(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/;
  var match = dateTime.exec(string);
  return new Date(Number(match[3]),
                  Number(match[2]) - 1,
                  Number(match[1]));
}

alert(findDate("30-01-2003"));
```

Also - I'd recommend reading [Regular Expressions - Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/09_regexp.html)

Comment: i declared  ` var date = "01/11/2015" ` in front of your *if* and its not working. Mozilla Firefox Web Console gave me next error:   SyntaxError: illegal character   Any idea why ?

Comment: SyntaxError: illegal character refers to line where *if* is.

Comment: I forgot to escape the backslashes. Edited above - try it again.

Comment: It's working but it has one flaw. I can put anything before or after date and I will still get *Valid input* .  `var date = "sssss01/02/2015"` or `var date = "01/02/2015sssss"` is still giving me *Valid input* .

Comment: See edit - I've added the `^` and `$` characters to enforce the start/end of the string. I've updated the JSFiddle as well.

Comment: Great! It works now. I will stick to first solution because it is completely satisfying. I'm gonna start investigating RegEx right away.

Comment: Good stuff! Glad I could help.

Comment: Neither solutions validate that the string is a valid date. `alert(findDate("30-01-2003"))` throws an error.

Comment: The OP requested that the format mm/dd/yyyy be used (so - naturally, 30-01-2003 would throw an invalid date error).

Comment: @OhHendrie—but 30/02/2015 does not when it should. There is also no reason to use `Number(match[…])`, the Date constructor is happy with strings so `match[…]` is sufficient since the regular expression has already checked that it's a number.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate the format and that it's a valid date, you have to check the values. That can be done with a regular expression but it's much simpler using a Date, e.g.

```
// Validate dd/mm/yyy date string
function isValidDMY(s) {
  var b = s.split('/');
  var d = new Date(b[2], --b[1], b[0]);
  return d && d.getMonth() == b[1];
}

console.log(isValidDMY('4/4/2015'));   // true
console.log(isValidDMY('29/2/2015'));  // false
```

There really is no point in insisting on leading zeros for single digit numbers for user input dates, so the above accepts either 4/4/2015 or 04/04/2015.

#### Edit

If you insist on leading zeros for day and month number, you can check that too by changing the last line to:

```
  return /^(\d\d\/){2}\d{4}$/.test(s) && d && d.getMonth() == b[1];
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work for me because i need those extra zeros because that date will be name for localStorage item. Since date is entered  in prompt by user i want to avoid any changes in form that may occur in that input. It may sound funny to you but its best i can do. Also, I'd like to know what does -- mean in `var d = new Date(b[2], --b[1], b[0]);` and what should statement after return do ?

Comment: It decrements the month number by 1 to correlate calendar month numbers with ECMAScript Date numbers. It modifies the value so it can be used later for checking the month number of the created date (and hence validating that it's a valid date).

Comment: @DusanJovicic `i want to avoid any changes in form that may occur in that input` Surely it's better to standardise it (`d.toISOString().split('T')[0]` or set to midnight and `+d`), tell it back to them in a wordy way (`d.toDateString()`) and use your standardised form in the _localStorage_? otherwise you could end up with many entries for the same date but formatted differently